# phonetic encryption

Tags: cipher

0x09f 6 Wilhelm Paula 67dsa7 Friedrich Josef Gustav Toni Caeser Dora Gustav Oh762d.
and
Joseph 78sada Paula Ludwig Friedrich Joseph 67das 7d Tony 87h677 Dora Gustav h7f ehfs. Ox 786 bds7fds Paula Ludwig Friedrich Joseph Gustav 67ds 78dfs7f 77ss 43fsd55 Richard.
165
Josef Wilhelm 76dsa Ludwig 43dsffssf Josef Gustav Toni Caeser Dora Gustav Richard.

Comment: What exactly is the puzzle here?

Comment: I think it's a pun. This text resembles the kind of output from mashing keys on a *phone* keyboard while allowing it to autocomplete words.

Comment: rot13(V abgvpr gung gur anzrf hfrq urer ner nyy va gur cubargvp nycunorg znexrq "Frpbaq Jbeyq Jne nycunorg" ba [guvf cntr](https://www.w2aee.columbia.edu/phonetic.html).)